# Format a USB disk on PURE FAT32, one partition only, on a Mac

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, format, fat32, exfat

There are other questions on SO about this, but not asking what I want.

I do not want to know how to format an external FAT32 disk from terminal, because this can be done by typing this:

```
sudo diskutil eraseDisk FAT32 MYDISK MBRFormat /dev/disk2
```

but this is the problem.

A disk formatted using this will be shown on disk util like this:

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 MYDISK                  2.0 TB     disk2s1
```

a real disk formatted by windows will appear like this

```
/dev/disk11 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            IOMEGA                 *1.0 TB     disk11
```

see that the Mac version has 2 partitions.

I have tried using `exFAT` instead of `FAT32`, on that command line. No change.

I am having problems using that Mac formatted disk as a shared disk on a router and the windows version works fine.

The problem is that I don't have windows anymore. This windows formatted disk I have was formatted years ago.

How do I do that?

Comment: The Mac version has 1 partition, the windows version 0 ...

Comment: While it is indeed possible to not have a partition table, there’s no drawback from having one. In fact, Windows also creates one if the device does not have a recognized file system.

Comment: @DanielB, I don't think you can say `there is no drawback from having one [partition table]` as the OP clearly stated that the partition was causing issues with his router disk sharing. I also need a FAT32 disk without partitions to flash a BIOS as my EZ-Flash BIOS doesn't understand partitions, and it also refuses to boot FreeDOS from a USB with partitions to run the `update.exe` utility. I resorted to passing the USB through to a Windows VM in Virtual Box that I had handy, but I'm sure there's an easy OSX/Linux way to do it.